# Can you validate a property based on another property using Yup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, frontend, yup

What I am trying to do is to validate that the password added by the user does not contain the username the they chose. On the frontend I do the validation with Yup and right know I have something like this:

```
export const schema = Yup.object({
  username: Yup.string()
    .required("Username is required")
    .matches(
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/,
      "The username should contain only alphanumeric characters, underscores and hyphens"
    ),
  password: Yup.string()
    .required("Password is required")
    .matches(
      /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{8,}$/,
      "The password should contain upper and lowercase letters, numbers and special characters"
    )
    // Here I should somehow check if the username value is used (maybe like this?)
    .matches(
      /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)(?!.*[{username}]).{1,}$/,
      "The password should not contain the username"
    )
});
```

I probably already do this wrong (with the username check part at least) so any other idea or suggestion on how to do this would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Yup ref and notOneOf to achieve this

```
import * as Yup from "yup";

const schema = Yup.object({
  username: Yup.string()
    .required("Username is required")
    .matches(
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/,
      "The username should contain only alphanumeric characters, underscores and hyphens"
    ),
  password: Yup.string()
    .required("Password is required")
    .matches(
      /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{8,}$/,
      "The password should contain upper and lowercase letters, numbers and special characters"
    )
    // Here I should somehow check if the username value is used (maybe like this?)
    .notOneOf([Yup.ref('username'), null], "The password should not contain the username")
 
    
});

 const obj = {
  username: 'abc',
  password: 'assscdF3$'
}

console.log(schema.validateSync(obj, {returnError: true}))

const obj2 = {
      username: 'assscdF3$',
      password: 'assscdF3$'
    }
    
    console.log(schema.validateSync(obj2, {returnError: true}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your should try this:

```
export const schema = Yup.object({
  username: Yup.string()
    .required("Username is required")
    .matches(
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/,
      "The username should contain only alphanumeric characters, underscores and hyphens"
    ),
  password: Yup.string()
    .required("Password is required")
    .matches(
      /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{8,}$/,
      "The password should contain upper and lowercase letters, numbers and special characters"
    )
    .test({
      name: 'username-check',
      message: 'Your error message',
      test: (value, ctx) => !value.includes(ctx.parent.username)
    }),
});
```